# How does Unison compute the hashes of recursive functions?

Tags: unison-lang

In Unison, functions are identified by the hashes of their ASTs instead of by their names.

Their [documentation](https://www.unison-lang.org/learn/language-reference/hashes/) and their [FAQs](https://www.unisonweb.org/docs/faq/) have given some explanations of the mechanism.

However, the example presented in the link is not clear to me how the hashing actually works:

They used an example

```
f x = g (x - 1)
g x = f (x / 2)
```

which in the first step of their hashing is converted to the following:

```
$0 = 
  f x = $0 (x - 1)
  g x = $0 (x / 2)
```

Doesn't this lose information about the definitions.

For the two following recursively-defined functions, how can the hashing distinguish them:

```
# definition 1
f x = g (x / 2)
g x = h (x + 1)
h x = f (x * 2 - 7)

# definition 2
f x = h (x / 2)
g x = f (x + 1)
h x = g (x * 2 - 7)
```

In my understanding, brutally converting all calling of `f` `g` and `h` to `$0` would make the two definitions undistinguishable from each other. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the form in the example (with `$0`) is not quite accurate. But in short, there's a special kind of hash (a "cycle hash") which is has the form `#h.n` where `h` is the hash of all the mutually recursive definitions taken together, and `n` is a number from `0` to the number of terms in the cycle. Each definition in the cycle gets the same hash, plus an index.

The long answer:

Upon seeing cyclical definitions, Unison captures them in a binding form called `Cycle`. It's a bit like a lambda, but introduces one bound variable for each definition in the cycle. References within the cycle are then replaced with those variables. So:

```
f x = g (x - 1)
g x = f (x / 2)
```

Internally becomes more like (this is not valid Unison syntax):

```
$0 = Cycle f g ->
  letrec
   [ x -> g (x - 1)
   , x -> f (x / 2) ]
```

It then hashes each of the lambdas inside the `letrec` and sorts them by that hash to get a canonical order. Then the whole cycle is hashed. Then these "cycle hashes" of the form `#h.n` get introduced at the top level for each lambda (where `h` is the hash of the whole cycle and `n` is the canonical index of each term), and the bound variables get replaced with the cycle hashes:

```
#h.0 = x -> #h.1 (x - 1)

#h.1 = x -> #h.0 (x / 2)

f = #h.0

g = #h.1
```